# Store two values from Dropdown Option Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I am using dropdown and it's option value is $account->code but it shows code and name

so i want to store code in its column and name in another column

here is my blade code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>@lang('site.from_account_number')</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="from_account_number" id="from_account_number">
        @foreach ($accounts as $account)
            <option value="{{ $account->code }}">
                {{ $account->code }} - {{ $account->name }} 
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

and here is my controller code :

```
$depositaction->from_account_number = $request->get('from_account_number');
$record_from_acc_name = Account::find($request->get('from_account_number'));
$depositaction->from_account_name = $record_from_acc_name->name;
```

but i get error said :

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
```

Comment: what's pk of the accounts table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query in code. Please check the below code.

```
$record_from_acc_name = Account::where('code', $request->get('from_account_number'))->first();
```